# Selenium Python not able to extract text within all span tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am creating a small python program that automates 10fastfingers. In order to do that, I have to first extract all the words that I have to type. All these words are stored within `span` tags like this:

[image]

When I run my code, it just extracts the first 20-30 words rather than extracting all the words. Why is this so? Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english"

browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

count = 1

wordlst = []

while True:
    
    try:
        word = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="row1"]/span[{count}]')
        wordlst.append(word.text)
        count += 1
        
    except:
        break

print(wordlst)
```

Output:

`['them', 'how', 'said', 'light', 'show', 'seem', 'not', 'two', 'under', 'hear', 'them', 'there', 'about', 'face', 'us', 'change', 'year', 'only', 'leave', 'number', 'found', 'father', 'people', 'house', 'really', 'my', 'spell', 'when', 'look', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

How to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with BeautifulSoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english"

browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
div = html_soup.find_all('div', id = 'row1')
wordlst=div[0].get_text().split()
browser.quit()
print(wordlst)
```

OR

to continue your approach,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english"
browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
wordlst=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="row1"]/span')
wordlst=[x.get_attribute("innerHTML") for x in wordlst]
browser.quit()
print(wordlst)
```

Comment: Hey! Thx man! That worked! Would u mind explaining what ```wordlst=div[0].get_text().split()``` exactly does? I haven't worked a lot with ```BeautifulSoup```, so I'm not able to understand what it exactly does.

Comment: Sure. Div returns a list of all the elements found with id 'row1'. ```get_text``` gives all the text in between the ```div``` tag including the ones from span while removing the tags. now since you want a list of words, i added split(). BeautifulSoup is usually used to work with html easily in python

Comment: Ok...Thx for the explanation! But wht is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach. It actually has a pretty simple solution. replace ```wordlst.append(word.text)``` with ```wordlst.append(word.get_attribute("innerHTML"))```. Actually you can make your code pretty small by simply using ```find_elements_by_xpath```

Comment: Ok...I followed the same logic to extract all the words to type in a multiplayer game, but I am getting a diff output. Would u like to help me? The url of all multiplayer games is https://10ff.net/login After logging in, this is wht I tried:

```html_soup = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

            div = html_soup.find_all('div', id = 'game')       
     
            wordlst=div[0].get_text().split()

            print(wordlst)```

Comment: And this is the output that I get:

```['Number', 'of', 'players', 'on', 'the', 'server:', '102', 'false', 'Bojin~', '0', 'WPM', 'Test', '0', 'WPM', 'ashu@16', '0', 'WPM', 'Matheus', '0', 'WPM', 'khurram', '0', 'WPM', 'notcloselinetheysaynobigwayindianbetweenverytakefollowthinksetoilownendgotmostanyintoworkquicklyatoroillargebeganthereoverpartcouldbeingsomethingfamilyfarundercitytogethereyefewlifedownbelowfewhearletenoughgettreeplacelatertheirmakelightmustdoesbeforestateanswergetotheranybeginletterfatheryousuchshow', 'New', 'Game', 'Version:', 'd05f']```

Comment: As u can see, all the words to type are in one sentence. Why is this so and how do I separate them?

Comment: Which code are you using? i am not able to get this kind of output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222059/discussion-between-sushil-and-yash-shah).

Comment: If u feel that my question is good and has been framed well, then pls consider upvoting my question. Thank you!